# Function called on each display of a view

Tags: sapui5

I have a view.
By `onInit` function i init the view. ok.
But what is the function that automatically fired when display a view?
For example I navigate my app forward and backward and I want for example that che content of the textarea are empty always?
What is the function that is called and where I write my code to set empty my textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the doc
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView.html

and the event handler is afterRendering. So you can do
    oView.attachAfterRendering(function() {
        
    });

-D

Comment: This isn't always true. onAfterRendering in standard views typically only gets called once, the first time it is rendered. If you are using a router to navigate between views, you can attach the patternMatched event to the route which will always fire.